# iCloudのKey-valueはデバイスごとに独立しているのか？

Tags: swift, iphone, icloud

swiftでiCloudを使ったアプリを作っています。

MyTextFieldという名前のText Fieldに入力した文字を以下のコードでiCloudのkey-valueに保存します。

```
let vStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default()
if let str = MyTextField.text {
        vStore.set(str, forKey: "inputText")
        vStore.synchronize()
}
```

またiCloudのkey-valueから値を取得するのに

```
let vStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default()
if let str = vStore.string(forKey: "inputText") {
    print("\(str))
}
```

で行いました。

一つのiPhone内では問題なくiCloudに保存して、値の読み込みも行えました。
しかし、同じアプリを異なる2つのiPhoneにインストールを行い同じApple IDを使用を試してみました。
片方が保存したkey-valueを、もう片方が読み出したときに読み出せません。
それぞれ独立している挙動をしているようです。

Key-valueは同じApple IDを使用していてもデバイスが異なれば、それぞれ独立しているのでしょうか？
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: 似ている気がしましたが試しましたか？ (当てはまりますか？)http://qiita.com/matsukaz/items/7cb611e1e7bcffd7a297

Answer (score 1):

NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreを複数のアプリで共有するにはEntitlements Plistファイルに同じ iCloudコンテナIDを設定する必要があります。

EntitlementsファイルはXcodeが自動的に作成して、アプリのバンドルIDが自動的に設定されています。複数のアプリで共有するにはその値を、いずれかのアプリのIDに合わせて変更します。

詳しくは公式ドキュメントの「Configuring Common Key-Value Storage for Multiple Apps」セクションをご覧ください。

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW26

Comment: まさに探していた内容だと思います。このXcodeが自動生成するEntitlementsファイルは中身をどうすれば確認できるのでしょうか？アプリで表示させてみようかと考えていますが、取得方法を読み取ることができず。ご存知であれば。

Comment: どういう意味でしょうか？iCloudをオンにすると、自動的に[プロジェクト名].entitlementsのファイルが作成されます。これはメタデータとして使われてビルド時や配布時に参照されるものです。アプリケーションには含まれないのでアプリケーションから見るということは通常しません。Xcodeやエディタを使用して編集します。